# Как правильно проверить, что пользователь является админом?

Tags: php, javascript

Делаю блог-сайт. Как правильно проверить, что пользователь является админом?

Comment: @gear, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-как... Через БД.
Делать запрос к свойствам юзера, там должно быть поле типа `is_admin`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if($user_name == $admin_name){
>  //code
> }
> ```

Можно через бд. Выдавать им привилегии.

```
0- простой юзер, 1 - подтвердил email, 2 - модератор ,3 - Забанен, 4 - админ.
```

> ```
> if($group == 4){
>  //code
> }
> ```

Comment: При добавлении новой группы посередине будет БИДА. Чтобы ее избежать, можно кодировать конкретные значения константами, или, лучше, сразу работать с ролями в виде строк.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду.
Не могли бы Вы мне пояснить, в чём проблема?

Comment: @Ololoevv, в том, что по коду будет разбросана куча этих четверок, что а) снижает вероятность беспроблемной замены их, скажем, на пятерку и б) увеличивает вероятность случайно поставить не то число. Лучше оперировать константами или функциями.

Answer (score 0):

А у меня на сайте вот так :

Есть поле **ustate** :

0 - пользователь забанен

1 - зареган, но ещё не активирован

2 - активирован

3 - админ

Каждый раз, когда запускается код, ты проверяешь по базе это поле

```
$sq = $ml->prepare('SELECT ustate, ...... FROM users WHERE id = '.$user['id'].' LIMIT 1');

$sq->execute();

$usac = $sq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;

define('USERS_USTATE', $usac['ustate']);
```

В других местах, куда можно пустить только админа, ты пишешь проверку :

```
if (USERS_USTATE == 3) {

 echo 'Вы админ, доступ открыт';

} else {

 echo 'Доступ закрыт';

}
```

Comment: Стоит ли так вшивать проверку?

Comment: через define точно не стоит.

Comment: @Etki, это был риторический вопрос с оттенком сарказма :)  
Группу, разрешения и прочее надо хранить в модели юзера...